# Using nested-query from NodeJS to connect MongoDB data and result of console and browser are not consistent?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using nested-query data from NodeJS to connect MongoDB as following snippet code:

```
router.get("/FindByUsernameAndPassword/:email/:password", function (req, res) {
    console.log('user.js -> /users ');
    var username = req.params.email;
    var password = req.params.password;
    console.log(username + " " + password);
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
        format = require('util').format;

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/NodeDB', function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var collection = db
            .collection('AppUser')
            .find({Username : username , Password : password})
            .toArray(function (err, items) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                //Find Role info from RoleId
                db.collection('Role')
                .find({RoleCode : items[0].RoleCode})
                .toArray (function (err, items2) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    items.Role = items2;
                    console.log(items);
                    res.json(items);
                });
            });
    });
});
```

As the code above I'm find the `AppUser` data by using `Username` and `Password` and then use `RoleCode` from result `items` to get data from Role collection.
Then I try to put the results `items2` into derived property `items.Role` and display `items`. In the display result I use both `res.json(items)` and `res.send(items)` and the result are same.

result in console :

```
[{_id: 54e6c0f2b76de97fe0ce07a9,
    Id: 1,
    Username: 'admin',
    Password: 'admin',
    StaffCode : '0001',
    RoleCode: 'RL0001'
    RoleName: 'Admin',
    RowId: 1,
    RoleId : 54e6c0f0b76de97fe0ce0738 },
    Role: [
        Id: 1,
        RoleCode: 'RL0001',
        RoleNameEn: 'Admin',
        RoleNameTh: 'ผู้ดูแลระบบ',
        RowId: 1 }]
]
```

Result in Chrome browser:

```
[{"_id":"54e6c0f2b76de97fe0ce07a9","Id":1,"Username":"admin","Password":"admin","StaffCode":"KZH0001","RoleCode":"RL0001","RoleName":"Admin","RowID":1,"RoleId":"54e6c0f0b76de97fe0ce0738"}]
```

The expected result is in the console and I don't know why in the browser is show only `AppUser` document not having `Role` property.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You met interesting behavior of `console.log`.

Example of that are you doing

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.Role = {}
console.log(a)
// -> [1, 2, 3, Role: Object]
```

But

```
JSON.stringify(a)
// -> "[1,2,3]"
```

You trying to serialize array properties. I think you should do something like

```
items[0].Role = items2;
```